# What does it mean for a breakpoint to be installed?

Tags: eclipse, breakpoints

The [documentation for Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) states that a blue circle icon represents an

> enabled line breakpoint

and that a checkmark is an

> adornment that marks a line breakpoints as installed

What's the difference between active, installed and enabled, when referring to breakpoints?  Is installed -- in this case -- an Eclipse-specific definition?

Comment: Just added "enabled breakpoint" description, as requested.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my Google-fu really let me down on this one.  +1/accepted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [thread (2002!)](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/newsLists/news.eclipse.tools/msg24184.html) has a good explanation for installed breakpoints

> Blue breakpoints mean that the breakpoint is not installed.
>   In older builds, a green icon means that the breakpoint was successfully installed.
>   **An installed breakpoint means that the class has been loaded in the target VM and a breakpoint request has been successfully created at the desired location (for a line breakpoint) for the current debug target**.
>
> In the current builds, an installed breakpoint is indicated with a small checkmark overlay icon on top of the blue "base" icon. [image: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/images/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui/ovr16/installed_ovr.png]
>
> A breakpoint may not been installed:
>
> - when the class is not loaded (or not yet loaded)
> - our breakpoint location verifier fails to identify a non-executable line of code and lets you place a breakpoint on that line.
> - when you run instead of debug.

---

As mentioned in [jdt documentation](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewsvn/index.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/concepts/cbrkpnts.htm?revision=1.31):

> - An enabled breakpoint causes a thread to suspend whenever the breakpoint is encountered. Enabled breakpoints are drawn with a blue circle [image: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/images/org.eclipse.debug.ui/obj16/brkp_obj.png] and have a checkmark overlay once successfully installed. A breakpoint can only be installed when the class the breakpoint is located in has been loaded by the VM.
> - A disabled breakpoint will not cause threads to suspend. Disabled breakpoints are drawn with a white circle [image: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/images/org.eclipse.debug.ui/obj16/brkpd_obj.png].

Comment: "Surely our users will understand the semantics of an 8 by 8 icon overlay on the breakpoint icon." - Eclipse UI team

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a breakpoint that's been compiled and is available next time you run.

Answer (score 0):

Installed means that the program will indeed hit that break point when debugging.