# Google App Engine java eclipse plug-in cannot suspend on exception. Is this normal?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

GAE java plugin does not suspend at any exception. So I'm seeing only stack-trace.
The exception is just simple type-casting exception from bug on my code. (Not a custom breakpoint)
I installed all tools with default setting and nothing configured additionally.
Is this normal?

And addition, DataNeucleus enhancing and app startup to debugging is so slow too. Is this normal too?

Env:

- Mac OS X 10.6.2
- Java SE 1.6.0_17 (bundle with OS)
- Eclipse + GAE plugin for Java. (without AJAX component, downloaded yesterday)

Comment: Are you sure you launch with Debug (F11) and not Run (ctrl-F11)?

Comment: Yes, I checked all launching buttons of run or debug.
I'm re-downloading tools I'll comment again after check it once more.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to [eclipse breapkpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799362/what-does-it-mean-for-a-breakpoint-to-be-installed/1799468#1799468) which are not respected, one possible cause is the bug [Breakpoints fail to hit under JDK 1.6.0_14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027002/eclipse-swing-app-breakpoint-hit-only-after-an-uncaught-exception-is-thrown/1027038#1027038)

So if you are using `jdk6u14` or `u15`, you need to upgrade your JVM.
That would not explain the slow behavior of the debugging session, but at least would solve one of the issues you mention.

Comment: My JVM was 1.6.0_17. Maybe a different problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Eonil It was worth mentioning anyway. I hope someone else has a more helpful answer on your specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add Java Exception Breakpoint(Run->Add Java Exception BreakPoint)?

Comment: I tried this, but this caught all kind of useless exceptions(outisde of my application scope) or cannot catch any exception.